# How to execute a simple stored pl/sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

`enter code here`**AFTER EDIT**

This is my first stored pl/sql program. I explain it to the basic that may cause the error:

I have a table of Account:

```
BSB#    CUSTOMER#   ACCOUNT# TYPE                    BALANCE
------ ---------- ---------- -------------------- ----------
012878     123456   12345678 Saving                  1234.52
012878     123456   22345678 credit                 -1534.52
012878     123456   32345678 Home loan            -453234.52
012878     123458   11001234 SAVING                  3213.54
012878     123458   21001234 Credit                  -120.34
```

I am trying to prompt account type from user input and display BSB#. here is my pl/sql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AQ (loan_type IN ACCOUNT.TYPE%TYPE) IS
    BSB_NUMBER  ACCOUNT.BSB#%TYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT A.BSB#
INTO  BSB_NUMBER
FROM ACCOUNT A
WHERE LOWER(A.TYPE) = LOAN_TYPE;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(BSB_NUMBER);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HELLO');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error ! There is no such account');
END AQ;
/
```

After putting this file inside my current directory I enter:

```
@AQ.sql
```

And output:

```
  Procedure created.
```

And for execution I enter:

```
SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> EXECUTE AQ('SAVING');

  ERROR at line 1: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows ORA-06512: at "BKG988.AQ", line 4 ORA-06512: at line 1 –
```

But there is no output... How can I print the output?
Appreciate if you let me know where is wrong!

Comment: 1) Formal parameters can not have restrictions in type - use loan_type IN VARCHAR2 
instead of loan_type IN VARCHAR2(10) - this is why your procedute is compiled invalid. 
2) to turn on dbms_output use SET SERVEROUTPUT ON before execution
3) 'SAVINGS' is in uppercase - why do you use LOWER() when ? If you want to
have case-insensitive code, use UPPER(A.TYPE) = UPPER(LOAN_TYPE) or (better) take
actions to prevent case-sensitive data in the table

Comment: Thanks for that. I did step 2 though.

Comment: If you get "*created with compilation errors*" use `show errors` to see the details.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Please have a look at the edit.

Comment: @Bernard, it seems that your table has more than one row where the type is equal to saving, so it is not possible to store it in the single variable and as a result you get this error.

Comment: And in addition, the answer below is incorrect, so you should change your dbms_output.put_line to the previous version: DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(BSB_NUMBER);

Comment: @Guneli Yes, I have changed it and so far there is no error but there is no output! Even it doesn't print 'hello'. Any idea?

Comment: Have you put serveroutput on?

Comment: @Guneli The error now is ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "BKG988.AQ", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: @Bernard, as I have told previously your table has more than one row where the type is equal to saving, so it is not possible to store it in the single variable and as a result you get this error. You said that you have corrected this, no?

Answer (score 0):

The error on statement is quite self-explanatory. Since your `select` statement returns more than 1 result and it can't be stored to a single variable. You can write a `trigger` inside your `procedure` to get the output.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is for Saving records there are couple of values returned as result set. Oracle Variable can hold only one values at a time. If you want them to hold multiple values, you should either use,
1. Varray
2. Nested Table
3. Associative Array.

But those aside, your problem could be addressed by having the select statement executed from a Ref Cursror

OPEN c_cur for SELECT A.BSB# FROM ACCOUNT A
WHERE LOWER(A.TYPE) = LOAN_TYPE;

instead of your normal select statement